# adding record to MYSQL database wont work in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Ive written PHP code to add a record to my database. When I click on the save button, then it should say "saved successfully", But all that happens is that the page refreshes with no added records in the database and no "saved successfully" message pops up.

My database connection works properly. So I cant figure out what the problem could be.

**here is the PHP code:**

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die("error");
if($con) {
    mysqli_select_db("maplibrary",$con);
}

if (isset($_POST["save"])) {
    $sql = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO member (memberID, firstName, surname, contactDetails) 
        VALUES('{$_POST['memberID']}',
            '{$_POST['firstName']}',
            '{$_POST['surname']}',
            '{$_POST['contactDetails']}'
            )");

    if ($sql) {
        echo "save successfully";
    }
}
?>
```

**here is the HTML code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>ViewMembers</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <table style="border:1 #F00 solid;width:500px;overflow:auto;margin:auto;background:#999;">
                <tr>
                    <td>Member ID</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name"memberID" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>First Name</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name"firstName" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>                
                    <td>Surname</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name"surname" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Contact Details</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name"contactDetails" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Save" name="save" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are wide open to [**SQL injection**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). *Never* pass user input directly into a query. Use prepared statements instead.

Comment: Hi @Jason Osborn if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add **$conn** as parameter of mysqli_query function.See usage :
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password") or die("error");
if($con)
{

    mysqli_select_db("maplibrary",$con);

}

if (isset($_POST["save"]))
{
    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO member
    (memberID,firstName,surname,contactDetails) 
        VALUES('{$_POST['memberID']}',
            '{$_POST['firstName']}',
            '{$_POST['surname']}',
            '{$_POST['contactDetails']}'
            )");

        if ($sql)
        {
            echo "save successfully";

        }

}

?>
```

Comment: sorry but this didn't seem to make any difference

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";//YOUR USER NAME!
$password = "password";//YOUR PASSWORD!
$dbname = "myDB"; //YOUR DB NAME!

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
if (isset($_POST["save"])){
  $var1 = $_POST['memberID'];
  $var2 = $_POST['firstName'];
  $var3 = $_POST['surname'];
  $var4 = $_POST['contactDetails'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO member(memberID,firstName,surname,contactDetails)
VALUES ('".$var1."', '".$var2."', '"$var3."', '"$var4."')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {echo "successfully saved";}
else {echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;}
}
$conn->close();

?>
```

hope i understood your problem... :)
BTW i suggest you to create a php file that will contain only the connection, because you may will need to connect to the database again in some point so you do not want to copy your code again and again...
so you can create a connect.php that will contain only the connection lines, you can include it (connect.php) inside of any page you want. it will make kit much easier. 
look at: [php include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Comment: thanks a lot! but unfortunately when I use this code the page doesn't even load...

Comment: okay i made minor adjustment to your code. But now i get this message when i click on save:Error: INSERT INTO member(memberID,firstName,surname,contactDetails) VALUES ('', '', '', '')
Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'memberID' at row 1

Comment: ok.
maybe you try to set a string instead of integer? i don't know what did you set on the table, but you must save the same type...

Comment: if you save an int so take off the first quests, should look like: ".$var2."  .
not like : ' ".$var2." '

Comment: ive set it to a Varchar and took the primary key off. and it saved. but now theres nothing added to the database.